# Bookmarklet not changing text in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I have created this bookmarklet to highlight the username and password boxes on a page.  I can change the colour of the boxes, but if I try to change the text in the box, it doesn't work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(var boxes= $(':text, :password');var selectionBox = $(':password');selectionBox.val('password');for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length;i++){if(boxes[i] == selectionBox[0]){boxes.eq(i-1).val('login');}})">Password box highlighter</a>
```

I have tried `.text = ''`, `.value = ''` and `.val('')`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code to execute into a function-call:

```
<a href="javascript:void(function(){var boxes= $(':text, :password');var selectionBox = $(':password');selectionBox.val('password');for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length;i++){if(boxes[i] == selectionBox[0]){boxes.eq(i-1).val('login');}}}())">Password box highlighter</a>
```

Explanation: void expects an expression(only 1 expression).

[An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Your code already breaks with the first var-keyword, because declaring a variable is not an expression.

When you wrap the code into a function-call, the expression is the function-call itself, no matter which code will be executed inside the function.